# How to map one social account to several user account with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I need to map one social account (created on a Django server with `django-oauth-toolkit`) to several different logins in a Django website. I already managed to connect and the server passes all allowed accounts so that the client connects as one of them.

I'd like to add the possibility to prompt for the choice of which of the accounts should be used. I'm currently connecting the user in the `pre_social_login` method of the account adapter.

The only idea I have is to persist in the session the available accounts and redirect to a page to select the preferred one. I'd like to understand if there's a better way.